# Test calling methods in same class with explicit receiver

Tags: ruby, program-entry-point

My job is to fill the `__` below (what is equal to `self.my_method...`).

```
def my_method_in_the_same_class(a, b)
  a * b
end

def test_calling_methods_in_same_class_with_explicit_receiver
  assert_equal __, self.my_method_in_the_same_class(3,4)
end
```

I get `NoMethodError: private method 'my_method_in_the_same_class' called for main:Object`. The correct answer is 12 and I don't know why I get this error. I can just type 12, but I guess that's not the point of learning.

Comment: Okey, I made it. It's all about classes. I had to create new class in IRB because there's already class created in PTE. I guess I am one step closer to enlightenment :)

Comment: Testing private methods is generally considered sketchy. You can always use `send` to call them, though.

Comment: @user3898922 if you provide the context, we may add the explanation why your method become private.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the private methods with `self` prefix, insead you should declare them as `protected`, or yes use `#send` method to call it (as correctly noted Dave). As example add after the method declaration:

```
protected :my_method_in_the_same_class
```

Comment: You should explain why the method became private.

Comment: @sawa I see not the context.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you put in `__`, the error will not disappear. The error is not coming from there.

Your method is defined in the `main` environment, which makes the methods private. Nevertheless, you are using `self` to call the method. That is the cause of the error. Even if it were not private, there is no reason to use `self` here.